# GAE Search API: Default value in order SortExpression

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-search

When setting sorting order option in SortExpression.Builder, it's strictly required to set a `defaultValue(String,Numeric or Date)`.

What is a purpose of this setting and how it affects search results or result sorting order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents in the index are not required to all have the same fields. If you try to sort on a field that some documents do not contain, we use the appropriate default value for that document. For example, if I had the following documents:

```
doc A: NumberField(name=x, value=7), TextField(name=y, value="hello")
doc B: NumberField(name=x, value=20), TextField(name=y, value="world")
doc C: TextField(name=y, value="hello")
```

In this case, if we sort on the field `x` with a default numeric value of `10`, we get `A, C, B`, but if the default numeric value is `0`, we get  `C, A, B`.